# Home machine legs workout obtain muscles

Tags: muscle-gain

[image: machine]recently my family bought this.I workout my full body to gain muscle.First can someone like  this machine obtain muscles on legs?Second,how much time and how many days should a thin guy do it.Third question should it be "normal mode" ,"soft" ,"hard"(I mean the difficult of doing it .What is more helpful of those to obtain muscles on legs.I avoid to refer the mark for no advertisements reasons.

Comment: You already have muscles on your legs.  You may be able to grow them for a very short time (for example, one or two weeks) by using this equipment.  For substantial growth, I suggest barbell strength training (squats).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your photo appears to show an Elliptical machine for aerobic/cardiac conditioning.  These types of machines don't typically provide enough resistance to stimulate hypertrophy.  Gaining muscle, specifically over your entire body, requires resistance training, sound nutrition, and rest.  You should look to supplement this machine with a strength training program geared towards your particular goals.  Either by going to a gym, or, performing body weight movements at home.

As far as the settings on the machine are concerned, that's something you'll need to decide based on your goals and your current ability.  Exercise machines usually have an owner's manual explaining their usage.  Consulting the manual should provide a starting point for you to decide on the settings.  Use your individual fitness goal as a decider on how often to use the machine.

Comment: I would second what's offered in the answer above. It seems you may not be familiar yet with the basic concepts and differences between cardiovascular and resistance training in relation to how they affect your body. Do read up a little on resistance training. Magazines such as Bodybuilding or Breaking Muscles have excellent articles on these matters. Once the concepts are clear to you, you'll be more informed on how to go about the tools and methods. The short of it is it does require all of what @rrirower has mentioned, including proper nutrition and proper rest and periodization.